# SELECTING WHERE from array in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to SELECT from an array inside a mysql query

```
result = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM fruit_db
WHERE fruit='".$url."'
")
```

$url has been created by $_GET and exploded into an array. It can be 'apple' or 'apple,banana,orange' for example. Not sure whether to implode back into string or not.

I need to be selecting 'apple' OR 'banana' OR 'orange', not 'apple,banana,orange'.

I'm used to counting the elements of the string, and looping through them, but not inside a mysql query, I can't work out if there's a simple way.
I've tried something like

```
/*    
    result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM fruit_db
    WHERE fruit='".$url[0]."'
    OR  fruit='".$url[1]."'
    // etc
    ")
*/
```

but I don't know how many elements there will be

Comment: You should use `IN`. And you should not use `myqsl_*` functions anymore.

Comment: I was going to say use the IN operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM fruit_db WHERE fruit IN ('".implode("','", $url)."')";
```

Suppose your `$url = array('apple','banana','orange');`

Then sql will be :

```
SELECT * FROM fruit_db WHERE fruit IN ('apple','banana','orange')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with `IN` with implode of the array `$url` like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fruit_db WHERE fruit IN (".implode(',',$url).")";
```

Make sure that `$url` is an array.

And try to avoid `mysql_*` statements due to the entire `ext/mysql PHP` extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_*`, is officially deprecated as of `PHP v5.5.0` and will be **removed in the future**.

There are two other `MySQL` extensions that you can better Use: `MySQLi` and `PDO_MySQL`, either of which can be used instead of `ext/mysql`.

Comment: Will do. once it is all working I will replace the deprecated syntax, thanks. Do I simply replace 'mysql_query' with 'MySQLi' or 'PDO_MySQL'? And do they return the same type of resource?

Comment: Yes ,May need some extra config for connection setup in mysqli_* and you can follow the using http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Again, you beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

you may use

SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN ("1","2");

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$url=explode(",",$_GET['fruit']);

foreach($url as $fr){
  $result = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM fruit_db
  WHERE fruit='".$fr."'
  ")
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I had before, can whoever down-voted explain why it's bad?